# How to pass data from a seprate file in my testcafe file

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

This is a kind of test I am trying to run in testcafe v1.0.1, I am relativelt new to this. 
 This my **test.js** file where I have three different test cases R03,  R05,R06 and all search for the element in a webpage using withText() function. 
Is there anyway for me make a config file(json/js) where I can save the inputs for Year_1,Year_2,Year_3, & Location_1, Location_2, Location_3 and use it in my current .js file.

```
`import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `First Fixture`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('R03', async t => {
    await t  
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Year_1'))
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Location_1'))
});

test('R05', async t => {
    await t
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Year_2'))
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Location_2'))
});

test('R06', async t => {
    await t
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Year_3'))
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText('Location_3'))
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot store inputs in some .js file.
But, you can save inputs' [selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html) and use them in your tests.
See example:

`element-selectors.json`

```json
{
  "developerNameInput": "#developer-name",
  "populateBtn": "#populate"
}
```

`test.js`

```js
fixture `Fixture`
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

const elementSelectors = require('./element-selectors.json');   
    
test('test', async t => {
    await t.typeText(elementSelectors.developerNameInput, 'Peter Parker');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this solution won't work for me, as I have the user who doesn't possess any knowledge about CSS selectors and just want to be able to configure a config file with relevant input (such as year, location etc). Also, the selectors change as the previous input are changed, so hardcoding the element-selector won't be of much help either.

Answer (score 3):

### Found a solution

Create a config.js file
**config.js**

```
export default {
        // Preview Paramters for R03 Report
        year:       '2019',
        Location:   'Dublin',
};
```

Now, let your main text file be test.js
**test.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import data from "./config.js"; 

fixture `First Fixture`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('R03', async t => {
    var year = data.year.toString();
    var location = data.location.toString();
    await t  
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText(year))
        .click(Selector('[data-bind^="css:{ \\\'dx-state-disabled\\\'].find('div').withText(location))
});
```

The  solution worked for me perfectly.
If someone had a better solution, I would be happy to implement and test it out.